# How to create utils with apollo-hooks for react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm making an authentication flow with two tokens(accessToken, refreshToken) on react-native/apollo-hooks/graphql. And created apollo-hook for updateTokens. And this hook i need to use in different components, because every time when user would like to do any actions like make a post or a comment i need to call updateTokens apollo hook. Therefore i need to take all logic of updateTokens to a separate utils, because i don't want repeat yourself and put everywhere the same code. But when i make separate util file with apollo hook it is not working. Can somebody explain me how can i make it please!

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native'
import { useMutation } from 'react-apollo-hooks'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain'

const UPDATE_TOKENS = gql`
  mutation UpdateTokens($accessToken: String!, $refreshToken: String!) {
    updateTokens(data: { accessToken: $accessToken, refreshToken: $refreshToken }) {
      user {
        name
        phone
      }
      accessToken
      refreshToken
    }
  }
`

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const update_tokens = useMutation(UPDATE_TOKENS)

  const updateTokens = (accessToken, refreshToken) => {
    console.log('accessToken', accessToken)
    console.log('refreshToken', refreshToken)
    update_tokens({
      variables: { accessToken, refreshToken },
      update: async (cache, { data }) => {
        const accessToken = data.updateTokens.accessToken
        const refreshToken = data.updateTokens.refreshToken
        await Keychain.setGenericPassword(accessToken, refreshToken)
      }
    }).then(() => console.log('We have new credentials'))
  }

  const getCredentials = async () => {
    const tokens = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
    console.log('tokens', tokens)
    const keyChainAccessToken = tokens.username
    const keyChainRefreshToken = tokens.password
    console.log('keyChainAccessToken', keyChainAccessToken)
    console.log('keyChainRefreshToken', keyChainRefreshToken)
    updateTokens(keyChainAccessToken, keyChainRefreshToken)
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="updateTokens" onPress={getCredentials} />
      <Button title="getCredentials" onPress={checkCredentials} />
      <Button title="SignOut" onPress={userSignOut} />
    </View>
  )
}
export { HomeScreen }
```

Can i put it to the separate file like this and use it after in different places:

```
import { useMutation } from 'react-apollo-hooks'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

const UPDATE_TOKENS = gql`
  mutation UpdateTokens($refreshToken: String!, $refreshTokenId: String!) {
    updateTokens(refreshToken: $refreshToken, refreshTokenId: $refreshTokenId) {
      user {
        name
        phone
      }
      accessToken
      refreshToken
    }
  }
`

const updateCredentials = () => {
  const update_tokens = useMutation(UPDATE_TOKENS)
  const updateTokens = (refreshToken, refreshTokenId) => {
    console.log('refreshToken', refreshToken)
    console.log('refreshTokenId', refreshTokenId)
    update_tokens({
      variables: { refreshToken, refreshTokenId },
      update: async (cache, { data }) => {
        const newAccessToken = data.updateTokens.accessToken
        const newRefreshToken = data.updateTokens.refreshToken
        const user = data.updateTokens.user
        await Keychain.setGenericPassword(newAccessToken, newRefreshToken)
      }
    }).then(() => console.log('We have new credentials'))
  }

  const getCredentials = async () => {
    try {
      const tokens = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
      console.log('tokens', tokens)
      const keychainAccessToken = tokens.username
      const keychainRefreshToken = tokens.password
      const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000
      const decodeAccessToken = jwtDecode(keychainAccessToken)
      console.log('decodeAccessToken', decodeAccessToken)
      const keychainRefreshTokenId = decodeAccessToken.refreshTokenId
      console.log('keychainRefreshTokenId', keychainRefreshTokenId)

      if (decodeAccessToken.exp > currentTime) {
        console.log('Credentials is still valid')
      } else if (decodeAccessToken.exp < currentTime) {
        console.log('Go to Update!')
        updateTokens(keychainRefreshToken, keychainRefreshTokenId)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Invalid credentials')
    }
  }
}
export { updateCredentials }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, I won't do this for refreshing token. I made a middleware for it.

***How to set middleware:***

```
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
const getClient = ({ userStore: { token, refreshToken: refresh_token }, lang }, dispatch) => {
    const locale = lang || 'en';

    const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
    });

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        link: ApolloLink.from([
            getTokensMiddleware(token, refresh_token, locale, dispatch),
            uploadLink
        ]),
        cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });

    return client;
};
```

***The middleware:***

```
const getTokensMiddleware = (token, refresh_token, locale, dispatch) => {
    return setContext(async (req, { headers, ...others }) => {
        if (!token || !refresh_token) return {};
        var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
        const isExpired = decoded.exp <= Date.now() / 1000 + 120;
        var decodedRefresh = jwtDecode(refresh_token);
        const isRefreshJWTExpired = decodedRefresh.exp <= Date.now() / 1000;
        if(isRefreshJWTExpired) return {};
        if (!isExpired) {
            return {
                ...others,
                headers: {
                    ...headers,
                    Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
                    locale
                }
            };
        }
        return new Promise((success, fail) => {
            refreshToken(refresh_token)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.json();
                    } else {
                        fail(response);
                    }
                })
                .then(json => {
                    const { token } = json.data.refreshToken;
                    dispatch({type: "login", payload: json.data.refreshToken})
                    success({
                        ...others,
                        headers: {
                            ...headers,
                            Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
                            locale
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    });
};
```

***Your refresh function:***

```
const refreshToken = refreshToken => {
    const data = {
        operation: 'RefreshTokenMutation',
        query:
            'mutation RefreshTokenMutation($email: String!, $refreshToken: String!) {  refreshToken(email: $email, refreshToken: $refreshToken) {    token    refreshToken    user {      id      email      username      displayname      role {        title        permissions        __typename      }      __typename    }    __typename  }}',
        variables: { email: 'admin_email', refreshToken: refreshToken }
    };
    return fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
};
```

***How to use it***

```
const AppPage = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useStore(); //a hook for getting context containing useReducer
    return (
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <Helmet>
                <title>My Project</title>
                <meta name="description" content="My project" />
            </Helmet>
            <ApolloProvider client={getClient(state, dispatch)}>
                <LocaleProvider locale={state.antdLocale}>
                    <App />
                </LocaleProvider>
            </ApolloProvider>
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer, but can you please explain where do you get this arguments when create a middleware: { userStore: { token, refreshToken: refresh_token }, lang }, dispatch? In my case it have to be from Keychain storage?

Comment: those variables are for my own use only, you can use your own way. They come from useReducer hook for getting and updating the token states.

Comment: Can you answer please for one more question. When the Apollo setContext is working? In the app's initialization moment or later? Because in my case i need to save token to setContext, but when the app's initializated the Keychain storage does not have any tokens, because the user has not looggedIn yet. He gets tokens only after signIn. And when he loggedOut the tokens are erasing. But i thing setContext is start to work in the beginning. Is it right?

Comment: getTokensMiddleware is a function to generate the middleware. It start when you set the ApolloClient. And the getClient is the function generating the apollo client. We use the tokens (state) to generate a new client during the app running. Once you update the tokens(state), it will generate a new client. Updated the ans for giving an example.

Comment: Where do you keep useReducer hook? Can you sent me an example please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fattomhk/1aca0b9b8834e1598db71673b292b065 .  The user.js is a lazy example, change those localstorage to keychain or other secure way.

Comment: my code are too lazy that in real case you might consider redux or other state management tool

Comment: But i don't understand how can i create the fields in userInitialState in user.js with async/await? Keychain works only with async/await

Comment: You could give an empty string and then update it with "dispatch".

Answer (score 1):

if you still want to do that, you might do it in HOC way.

```
import React from 'react';
import YOUR_FUNCTIONS from '~/functions_location';

const withRefreshToken = () => (Component) => {
    return <Component {...YOUR_FUNCTIONS} />
};

export {
    withRefreshToken
}
```

after that you can do it like:

```
export default withRefreshToken(HomeScreen);
```